# How to return updated row or None when no row was updated?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to return the row I updated in Slick 2.1.0, but I am unsure of how to do so. The default return type is just an integer. Is there a way of returning the actual updated row?

I want to have a method of this signature type:

```
  /**
   * @param address the address to be updated in a database
   * @return the future value of the address if it exists, else none
   */
  override def update(address: Future[Address]): Future[Option[Address]] = {
    val updatedRow = for (
      addr <- address;
      q = addresses.filter(_.address === addr.address)
    ) yield addresses returning queryToUpdateInvoker(q).update(addr)

    updatedRow
  }
```

If the row is found, it returns the newly updated row, if it is not found we return none. I tried to do something similar to inserting a row, and then returning it to no avail.